# Where is code coverage window in my IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

Where can I find [Coverage Tool Window](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/coverage-tool-window.html) in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 11.02? In tutorial they say it is in View | Tool Windows | Coverage. But in my IDEA it isn't, see picture:

[image: Missing coverage window]

I have coverage plugin enabled.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to click on the **Run with Coverage** button in the toolbar, after tests complete, **Coverage** panel will appear showing the results of the run.

Comment: It doesn't. There will be percentage next to files in Project view, but not coverage tool window :/

Comment: I've verified and it works fine with my JUnit configuration (after run with coverage the panel appears automatically). Can you provide a link to a screencast showing how you run it (http://www.screenr.com/)?

Comment: Hey, here is the recording. I open project from sratch, run tests with coverage and no coverage window popped :(
http://screenr.com/IIm8

Comment: This panel appears only if all the tests pass, while your test fails.

Comment: Well I commented out line that makes test fail, but result is same, no popup ... are you sure there is absolutely no way how to bring that window from basic menu? Or maybe something with setting up JUnit ?

Comment: Can you share a sample project that doesn't open coverage panel?

Comment: I upgraded my IntelliJ to 11.1.2 and it works properly now. thank you for your help though!

Comment: Yeah! Work for me :D

Answer (score 0):

Run-->edit configurations--->select code coverage ( then you can select IDEA/EMMA/JaCoCo